# Следует ли использовать два return-а в одном методе?

Tags: java

Корректен ли следующий код, следует ли так писать, если нет то какие есть опасности, подводные камни?

```
public static boolean SomeMethod(int someVariable){
        for (blah-blah){
            if (blah-blah-blah){
                return CONST_TRUE;
            }
        }
        return CONST_FALSE;
}
```

Comment: - Вообще, в этом псевдокоде угадывается линейный поиск, который неплохо парсится при чтении, поэтому ничего плохого в нем нет. Таким же образом, например, написан [вот этот вот метод ALLCPAQuery.eval](https://code.google.com/p/cpachecker/source/browse/trunk/src/org/sosy_lab/cpachecker/cpa/automaton/AutomatonBoolExpr.java#201).

- Вцелом, если делать то же самое с помощью [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries) или [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/), то вы могли бы воспользоваться методом `find` для коллекций, подсунув ему свой предикат.

Comment: Корректен с какой точки зрения? С точки зрения компилятора, или задачи, или еще чего-то? В чем конкретно ваша проблема?

Comment: Правило «single entry/single exit» для языков, в которых практически любой вызов может бросить исключение — анахронизм.

Comment: Из праздного любопытства: почему `CONST_TRUE`? Вас заставили придерживаться правила о недопустимости магических значений даже для типа boolean?

Comment: Задание поставленного так, что результатом должна битовая константа произвольного значения. Оно должно быть совместимо с java 1.1 и содержать как можно меньше import-ов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Несколько `return`'ов могут привести только к ухудшению читабельности. Происки что дескать компилятор все равно сам соптимизирует - не работают, поскольку все зависит от компилятора: версии/вендора и проч.

Так уже сложилось, что прогер инстинктивно ищет возвращаемое значение в самом конце метода. В данном случае, метод небольшой и это не страшно - сразу видно что есть 2 точки выхода. Если же метод будет длинный (условно говоря, больше экрана монитора), то есть опасность что при изучении кода сторонний прогер упустит все возможные опции выхода. Отсюда и рекомендация: для маленьких методов несколько точек выхода не мешают, для больших все таки желательно точку выхода оставить одну сработав через `break` и переменную содержащую значение выхода.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно использовать флаги и выход из цикла. Может быть более наглядным.

```
public static boolean SomeMethod(int someVariable){
boolean is_blah_blah_expression=false
    for (blah-blah){
        if (blah-blah-blah){
            is_blah_blah_expression = true;
            break;

        }
    }
    if(is_blah_blah_expression)return CONST_TRUE
    else return CONST_FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на вопрос СУГУБО по стилю. Одни пишут так, другие иначе. Лишь бы везде писалось одинаково.

Один return исторически писали в С и С++. В java обычно пишут несколько return'ов.
У каждого подхода свои приверженцы и противники.

Мне странно читать комментарий [@Barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley) ♦, что для больших методов нужен один return. Больших методов не должно быть *в принципе*. Практика же вводит свои коррективы.

Сейчас ищу место в книге - то ли Мартин "Чистый код", тол и МакКонелл "Совершенный код", где кто-то из этих людей агитируют за множественные return из метода/процедуры. Всё зависит читабельности кода и как принято в конкретной кодовой базе.

Comment: *Больших методов не должно быть в принципе* - готов подписаться под каждым словом, но в реальности большие методы есть. Трудно отказаться от них в случаях `switch/case` или анонимных классов - так что мир не идеален, увы.